# Random Variable X, has distribution function...

Tags: probability

If $F_x=0$ if  $x<-1, 0.5$ if$ -1<=x<0, 2/3$ if $0\le x<1$ and $1$ if $x\ge1$,

Find $P(x<0)$, $P(x>0)$ and  $P(-1<x<1)$

I found that,

$$P(x<0)=0.5$$
$$P(x>0)=0.5$$
$$p(-1<x<1)=2/3$$

Can someone double check this for me. I am not sure about $P(x>0)$ because it is not inclusive with $0$.

Comment: The events $\{X<0\}$, $\{X=0\}$ and $\{X>0\}$ form a partition of the probability space. So $P(X<0)+P(X=0)+P(X>0)=1$. That would imply $P(X=0)=0$ if indeed $P(X<0)=P(X>0)=0.5$. However, that is not the case.

Comment: OP: What is your approach to this kind of question, in general?

Comment: I am not too sure. I was just given the distribution function and told to find those values. I just looked at those values and made an inference